# Serialize XML (via IXmlSerializable) to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk

I'm trying to write an XmlDocument from an instance of a class to pass to BizTalk (2006 R2, if it matters).  I'm implementing IXmlSerializable because I believe it'll give me the most flexibility (this object won't necessarilly always be written to an XmlDocument and passed to BizTalk).

So, I have implemented IXmlSerializable, and now I'd like to use the Write() method to create the actual XmlDocument instance to be passed to BizTalk.  Something like:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(XmlWriter.Create(this.Write());
```

Obviously the above doesn't work: I'm pretty sure it doesn't even compile... but that's the functionality I'm looking for.

Does anyone have a canned solution for this, or a place I can go to look for examples or a tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IXmlSerializable` is implemented when you would like to add custom serialization logic, this means that you need to use the `XmlSerializer` to have it call your implemented logic.

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
ser.Serialize(stream, this);
```

stream could be `XmlWriter`, `TextWriter`, `Stream` which you can then load into `XmlDocument` if you wish.

Here is some more info

[IXmlSerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)

Comment: Ah!  That makes much more sense.  I don't know why I completely forgot about XmlSerializer...